# Cluster install of gdal: Gdalinfo hdf "not recognized as a supported file format"

Tags: linux, gdal

We have gdal installed on a University cluster. The current install doesn't recognise HDF files (Modis HDF-EOS2?). What specific compile settings do we need for these formats? Any links to guide our cluster administrators would be appreciated.

Versions and formats:

Scientific Linux

gdal version: 3.1.3

sqlite version: 3.33.0

```
$ gdalinfo --formats | grep "HDF"
HDF4 (ros): Hierarchical Data Format Release 4
HDF4Image (rw+): HDF4 Dataset
HDF5 (ros): Hierarchical Data Format Release 5
HDF5Image (ro): HDF5 Dataset
```

Errors:

gdal_translate throws an error that a Modis HDF file is not recognised.

gdalinfo MCD12Q21.hdf

not recognized as a supported file format